# How to make a web view app for windows phone in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I am new to visual studio and I am going to do an windows-phone app with just a web-view that starts at a specific url, and nothing more..

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you can do is add a WebBrowser control to your main page. Then set its source equal to the Url you want.

If you want to do it in code then you can add the WebBrowser control via XAML then in the form loaded event or what ever event you would like, do `WebBrowser.Source = new Uri(@"www.yourSoruce.com");`

The WebBrowser control documentation is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.105).aspx

### EDIT

The above is to just set the source of the web browser. If you want it to load on launch then you need to put a navigate method in your constructor on your main page

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But is there something else i have to do in order for it to work? I have added the web browser and the source to my url but when i run it in the simulator it does not work, and it is nothing wrong with the url because I've tried with http://www.google.se also and it doesn't work then either..

Comment: @CorneliaG you're new to stack overflow so ill let it slide this time but you need to post code from now on when you post kimosabi.

Comment: @CorneliaG There's the solution. please make sure to upvote and check the answer if it works for you.